# In this code what does this refer to?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and this is from a tutorial from tutsplus.
In this code what does `this` refer to?

```
function addToCart(price) {
    if (this.total) {
        this.total  = 0;
    } 

    this.total += price;
    return this.name + '\'s cart total is £' + this.total;
}
```

Comment: Research and learning the basics of javascript will answer your question. It's the reason for tutorials right?

Comment: If you don't know how to search it, search for `javascript this keyword`.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a help forum, it's more of a Q&A style encyclopedia. If you can't present your problem in a generic way that, once answered, could be useful to everyone, then this isn't the place to ask. Especially when you don't know the basics in the language you're asking about.

Comment: I agree with the previous commenters. Your question should have a specific question or issue, and your post contains neither.

Answer (score -1):

The code you've posted above doesn't look 100% correct to me. The idea of the Tut's tutorial, I'm assuming, is to teach you Javascript Object Oriented Programming basics.

I've created a commented JSfiddle here, using your above example. I hope this helps a little bit to answer your question.

https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/vtndfL1y/

Here is the JS inside the above fiddle:

```
// Define function which will be our Object
function cart(name) {

    // Define a name for cart. Default to 'Bob' if undefined.
    this.name = name || 'Bob';

  // addToCart method on object.
  this.addToCart = function(price) {

    // If there is no total, set the total to zero.
    if (!this.total) {
      this.total = 0;
    }

    // Increment total by passed in price parameter
    this.total += price;

    // Return the string containing the total value.
    return this.name + '\'s cart total is £' + this.total;
  }
}

// Construct cart object
var cart = new cart('Mario');

// Set event listener on the button.
document.getElementById('cart_button').onclick = function() {

  // On each click, update the cart price incrementing by 5.
  document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = cart.addToCart(5);
}
```